# Running time of algorithms, fastest to slowest worst-case

Tags: algorithm

Given W1(n) = 100n; W2(n) = 2n log10 n; W3(n) = 0.1n^2
Order these from fastest to slowest in the sense of asymptotic worst-case running time.
For the worst case running time do we assume a small n so I made n = 1 and the order from fastest to slowest is W3, W2, W1.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happened with your textbooks? I wonder that somebody upvoted such question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the worst case running time do we assume a small n so I made n = 1

No, we don't assume any `n`. Asymptotic running time is about how the functions grow in comparison to each other as `n` grows. It's not interesting or relevant to test for a single value of `n`.

Assuming those three functions give the worst case running time, the order from fastest to slowest is, the opposite of what you proposed:

```
W1 = Ө(n)
W2 = Ө(n log n)
W3 = Ө(n²)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot makes sense now